# How do time multiple parts of a C code elegantly and without being so verbose?

Tags: c

I am timing many different parts of a C code only if the flag `timing==1` and I want different timings to go into different variables.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
if (timing) {time1=getTime}
foo(A);
bar(A);
if (timing) {elapsed1+=getTime-time1;}

if (timing) {time2=getTime}
bar(A);
if (timing) {elapsed2+=getTime-time2;

if (timing) {time2=getTime}
bar(C);
if (timing) {elapsed2+=getTime-time2;

if (timing) {time1=getTime}
foo(A);
fun(B);
if (timing) {elapsed1+=getTime-time1;}
```

However, this is long and ugly. Is there a nicer way to instead do something shorter and more elegant? For example it could be:

```
time1+=TIMEIT{
foo(A);
bar(A);
}

time2+=TIMEIT{
bar(A);
}

time2+=TIMEIT{
bar(B);
}

time1+=TIMEIT{
foo(A);
fun(B);
}
```

where timeit returns `0` if `timing==0` or otherwise the time taken by the block in the `{}`.

Also, is there a way to automatically figure out how much time a code block - or the entire code - spends calling on, say, calls to bar() and foo() - but not fun() and swiz() without profiling the entire code? If so, would this worsen performance?

More specifically, it would be something like:

```
time+=TIMECALLSTOBARANDFOO{
foo(A);
bar(B);
swiz(foo(A));
...
fun(A);
bar(C);
...
}
```

where `timebar` would contain only the time spent on calls to `bar` and `foo` but not on the rest of the stuff there.

I'm using gcc through mex on Linux.

Comment: Why not compile with -Pg, run the program for a while, then gprof >profile.txt and last less profile.txt ?

Comment: @ulix because that could fail spectacularly if he's using MSVC under Windows.

Comment: @dgnuff no reference to MSVS nor windows in question. Anyway there is a tool called mingw.

Comment: @ulix No reference to MSVC?  [That proves nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance)

Comment: @dgnuff that proves i'm NOT forced on suggesting someting on msvc. Bye bye.

Comment: @dgnuff -- how is your suggestion that MSVC is important here [not an argument from ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance) in the absence of any suggestion from OP that they are working in Windows?

Comment: @DavidBowling It's simply that in the absence of **ANY** information from the OP regarding what compiler / environment is in use, suggesting something that **ASSUMES** the use of GCC is not a useful comment.  I'm not saying he **IS** using MSVC, I'm saying we don't for for certain he's using GCC.  Does my argument make sense now?

Comment: @dgnuff -- not really. I think that ulix' comment was useful, and OP can decide for themselves whether gprof is an option or not, or may choose to provide more information (which would be good). Better comments than sniping about arguments from ignorance might suggest to the OP that more information would lead to better answers.

Comment: @dgnuff I'm actually using gcc through mex on linux. Thanks for making me aware that the solution fails if using windows.

Comment: Ideally, the comment from @ulix would start _"If you are using GCC, why not …"_ but it hardly seems fair to castigate him for a suggestion that omits the caveat but  might be helpful to the OP — and which subsequent information shows could be useful since the OP is working on Linux with GCC.  For **avgn**: please include summary platform information in the question; it helps avoid these problems.

Comment: How long do the functions take on each call?  Unless each of the functions is quite complex, you are likely to find that you're adding tiny parts of a second rather frequently, and that the timing is somewhat inaccurate.  That's true even if your system provides nano-second resolution (`clock_gettime()`, for example; see also `clock_getres()`).  Normally, you aim to time things that will take multiple milliseconds or longer — that sort of length of timing tends to be more accurate.  If you're down in the microseconds (or worse, nanoseconds) range, meaningful timing is harder.

Comment: So, your coding of timing is both long-winded and probably not very informative.  You'd probably do better working with profiling tools, but even those are more reliable when you're measuring longer time intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a macro to invoke the timing logic based on the value in your variable 'timing'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int elapsed1 = 0, time1 = 0;
int timing = -1;

#define TIMEIT(x) \
if (timing) {\
time1=getTime();} \
x;\
if (timing) {elapsed1+=getTime()-time1;}


void a(void);
int getTime();

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    timing = -1;
    TIMEIT(a());

    timing = 0;
    TIMEIT(a());

    return 0;
}
void a(void) {printf("\n Hello from a()");}
int getTime() {printf("\n Hello from getTime()"); return 42;}
```

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in "do { .... } while(0)" to handle things like if (x) TIMEIT(y)...

Comment: @DrC Awesome fix!